# Raku mode for xemacs?

Tags: raku, xemacs

I'm using Xemacs (not GNU Emacs) for ages, as I like it's interface better (and in days of yore, it's support for LaTeX/BibTeX and related tools was much better). But there seems to be no official Raku (neé Perl 6) mode around. There is one for GNU Emacs, but it seems to depend on lots of GNU Emacs infrastructure. Is there some extraofficial mode available? Or at least some guide for some elisp-ignorant to shoehorn/port the GNU Emacs one to Xemacs?

Answer (score 3):

The [`raku-mode` is developed in this repo](https://github.com/Raku/raku-mode/). Maybe you can open an issue there, or fork and make it work for xemacs.

Comment: It talks about a lot of GNU Emacs-only infrastructure, I hoped there was a native Xemacs one. Oh, well.